# TextView background not appearing when on top of a VideoView

Tags: android

I am using the merge layout to have my TextView appear on top of my VideoView. Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNote"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100px"        
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#A000"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
/>

</merge>
```

I have placed a "android:background="#A000"" property on my TextBox, but still it won't appear. All that appears is the white text with transparent background. When I changed the VideoView to an ImageView, the TextView background appears. I wonder why the TextView background would appear on top of an ImageView but not on top of a VideoView. Any suggestions will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: How about using non-transparent background? What is the result?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even when i set the background to "#F000" it would still show a transparent TextView background :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about merge, but I think, LinearLayout should do it...

Comment: I use merge so that TextView can be viewed on top (foreground) of the VideoView. I don't know how to do that on LinearLayout.